# Does the question, "Does S correspond to a fact?" meaningfully exist even if "corresponds to a fact" is not the same as "is true"?

Tags: truth

Or, then, do all questions involving the substitute for "is true" in some or another truth theory, exist as meaningful questions? So that any of the following is admissible on its own terms (on its own merits):

1. "Does S cohere with an ideal set of other sentences/propositions?"
2. "Is S the limit of an ideal inquiry?"
3. "Is S identical to some fact?" (Maybe have "B" instead, for beliefs, with the possibility of a strong overlap between the inherent content of B and the content of some fact, as with beliefs about beliefs, perhaps.)
4. "Is S (or B) constituted by some fact?"
5. "Does S satisfy the truth axioms for some axiomatic theory of truth?"
6. "S is *p*?" (instead of, "Is, 'S is *p*,' true?" for deflationism).

**Is it more or less efficient/useful to ask, "Is S true?" instead of whether S satisfies specific substituted characterizations of "is true"?** Or then can questions of truth be "paraphrased away" into an ensemble of other such questions, and none of those questions is to be dismissed out of hand *a priori* (even if some individual S conform to only some of (1) through (6), e.g. perhaps moral claims never substantively correspond to facts but do nontrivially cohere with ideal proposition sets, or whatever)?

---

Or, to frame the issue I'm having a little differently, can Quine's dictum about logic be expressed as, "Change the *meta*logic, change the (meta-)subject"? So that coherence theories of truth turn out to not be about truth at all (coherence seems like an outlier when compared to correspondence vs. constitution/identity, while pragmatic/inquiry-based theories can accommodate correspondence).

Comment: Didn't Plato pose this about math and the physical world? Math can't represent (depict versimilitudinously) because of the divided ontology, but must correspond to be helpful in the physical realm, which it clearly is.

Comment: @JKusin I wonder what Plato's/Socrates' analysis of the truth concept was, alongside the analysis of knowledge in the *Theaetetus*. Sometimes Plato seems to promote conceptual analysis, sometimes he seems hesitant about it; and in the *Meno* (IIRC) he poses the meta-issue of conceptually analyzing conceptual analysis itself. IIRC, his highest flight-of-fancy (in the *Republic*) ranks the Form of the Good above even the Form of the Truth.

Comment: To me the question is simple because you've removed the truth aspect of correspondence. We now longer have to worry how exactly things correspond in our heads to thing outside our heads with your alleviated condition, for example. Now, the correspondence in thorny cases (like toward non-existent objects) reduces to pragmatics, avoiding the analysis you bring up in your comment.

Comment: @JKusin yes, and couldn't we go on to ask whether claims mentioning nonexistent objects are coherent with some ideal set of propositions, or if such claims are constituted by facts (instead of corresponding to them), etc.? But I suppose the concept of facts might be taken to involve some elementary concept of truth, too (or what would ever be "ideal" about sets of propositions or inquiries, for that matter?).

Comment: To me correspondence still survives without an elementary idea of truth because something still bears on which propositions or statements to apply, and it might be mostly in the thing itself (reducing pragmatic concerns)--in a way that doesn't have to deal with overall cohering, and is less stringent than constitutive requirements. But maybe it does get subsumed by pragmatics, or maybe Plato has a way between truth and pragmatics. Curious what others will say to your general question

Comment: If you are asking, is it worth trying to understand 'true' in terms of other properties such as satisfaction and reference, then yes. Our understanding of truth has gained a lot from the work of Tarski and Kripke. If you are asking about whether truth requires correspondence to facts, then not for the antirealist. A moral antirealist might perhaps want to claim that some moral judgments are true, even though there are no moral facts. Putnam has argued that a deflationary theory of truth is antirealist.

Comment: @Bumble I can see that things like "'T' is true iff T" are useful, but they seem like they would be useful if written down even as, "'T' is xrue iff T," etc. So I don't see how much use the word "truth" has apart from the various proposed substitutes; but then the proposed substitutes already have their own meaning, and we can ask about them for their own sake. I'd say my question is of a piece with my increasing skepticism about the utility of conceptual analysis, esp. for highly generalized/abstract terms.

Comment: Hi Kristian, that's another fantastic KB question that I'll have to mull-over for several hours before I can even start to figure out how what I think about it!

Comment: I'll just cheer from the sidelines :-)